Limiting Slicer options based on other slicer selections
I'm using 3 slicers with 2 line charts.
Slicer 1 and 3 are both the same topic (just different makes of the same thing) and 2 is the specific model.
The 2 line charts are based on Slicer 1 and Slicer 3
So say the topic is Cars
Slicer 1. is car manufacturer - and line chart is sales by month based on the car class
Slicer 2. is the car class (Hatchback, Coupe etc.)
Slicer 3. Is the car manufacturers (Competitors of the group in 1) and their sales by month
My problem is, I want Slicer 3 to only show me the relevent available car classes based on the car manufacturer selected in Slicer 1.
So if in Slicer 1 we choose Ford, and they only have 3 classes available, then all I want to see in the 2nd line chart is the graph of the competitors sales for those 3 classes.
Currently my dashboard is showing me the individual line chart when I select an individual option, however if I click "all" it is showing me sales for all classes, not just those classes that are available to the option from the first slicer.
Does anyone know how I can have this as an option only of the subset available in slicer 1?
I hope that makes sense!
Thanks,
N
